# Autorenewable Subscritption Implementation

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I am having the below concern when implementing auto-renewable subscription - in-app purchase inside my app.

I am finding the difficult scenario on offering the poems under auto renewable subscription.I have referred [this](http://www.marco.org/2012/01/06/autorenewable-subscription-restrictions) url.By reading this i am got confused that whether i can offer poems via Autorenewable subscription or not?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Whether Apple lets you do auto-renewing subscriptions or makes you do non-renewing subscriptions is less about your content and more about how it is delivered. I assume you have already read the information in the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/13_ManagingIn-AppPurchases_Robert/ManagingIn-AppPurchases.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH4-SW1). You should also watch the [WWDC Video from 2012](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) about Supporting Subscriptions (it is 308) and it will give examples about when to use what kind of subscription.

I have recently done an app with subscriptions and we were initially rejected for auto-renewing and told to use non-renewing subscriptions. As best I can understand, you will use auto-renewing if you are creating original content on a set, regular basis and have built your app so that there are logical units (like a monthly newsletter or magazine). In my case, the user was subscribing to a series of blog entries that are updated every few days. However, the entries are presented in a single table view listing sorted by date and not separated into any kind of daily or weekly units.

Again I cannot tell from your question how the poems will be presented, but my suggestion would be to review the above documentation and if you are not 100% sure that you clearly fit into one of the auto-renewing subscription categories, submit your app with non-renewing subscriptions.